# Iterating array in declared function of bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, replace, declare

I've been working through creating a script to move some files from a local machine to a remote server. As part of that process I have a function that can either be called directly or wrapped with 'declare -fp' and sent along to an ssh command. The code I have so far looks like this:

```
export REMOTE_HOST=myserver
export TMP=eyerep-files

doTest()
{
    echo "Test moving files from $TMP with arg $1"
    declare -A files=(["abc"]="123" ["xyz"]="789")
    echo "Files: ${!files[@]}"
    for key in "${!files[@]}"
    do
        echo "$key => ${files[$key]}"
    done
}

moveTest()
{
    echo "attempting move with wrapped function"    
    ssh -t "$REMOTE_HOST" "$(declare -fp doTest|envsubst); doTest ${1@Q}"
}

moveTest $2
```

If I run the script with something like

```
./myscript.sh test dev
```

I get the output

```
attempting move with wrapped function
Test moving files from eyerep-files with arg dev
Files: abc xyz
bash: line 7:  => ${files[]}: bad substitution
```

It seems like the string expansion for the for loop is not working correctly. Is this expected behaviour? If so, is there an alternative way to loop through an array that would avoid this issue?

Comment: Why do you use `envsubst` ?

Comment: @Fravadona He's using it to copy the function definition to the remote machine.

Comment: You shouldn't have used `envsubst`. It relies on re-evaluation of code.

Comment: `envsubst` is replacing `$key` with an empty string.

Comment: Just write a script, copy it to the remote machine, then execute it remotely. `ssh` isn't designed to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: The main problem with this approach is that the remote host isn't guarantied to run the same version of bash, or even bash.

Comment: `ssh -t "$REMOTE_HOST" "bash -s" <<<"$(declare -f doTest); $(declare -p files); set -- $(printf '%q ' "$@"); "' doTest "$1"'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're confident that your remote account's default shell is bash, this might look like:

```
moveTest() {
    ssh -t "$REMOTE_HOST" "$(declare -f doTest; declare -p $(compgen -e)); doTest ${1@Q}"
}
```

If you aren't, it might instead be:

```
moveTest() {
    ssh -t "$REMOTE_HOST" 'exec bash -s' <<EOF
set -- ${@@Q}
$(declare -f doTest; declare -p $(compgen -e))
doTest \"\$@\"
EOF
}
```

Comment: This works. The only change I had to make was adding a missing closing ')'. It should be ssh -t "$REMOTE_HOST" "$(declare -f doTest; declare -p $(compgen -e)); doTest ${1@Q}"

Answer (score -1):

I managed to find an answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294378/replacing-only-specific-variables-with-envsubst/294400

Since I'm exporting the global variables, I can get a list of them using compgen and use that list with envsubst to specify which variables I want to replace. My finished function ended up looking like:

```
moveTest()
{
    echo "attempting move with wrapped function"
    ssh -t "$REMOTE_HOST" "$(declare -fp doTest|envsubst "$(compgen -e | awk '$0="${"$0"}"') '${1}'"); doTest ${1@Q}"
}
```

Comment: Don't use `envsubst` _at all_. You don't need it in any way whatsoever. Just use `declare -p` to copy your variables the same way you use `declare -f` to copy your function.

Comment: Think about what `envsubst` is doing here: You're substituting literal data into code. That introduces serious potential for bugs, _including_ security risk, if that data contains anything that doesn't parse to itself.

Comment: ...and data that doesn't evaluate back to itself when parsed as a literal is _very_ common. You put quotes in your data that match the surrounding ones and you're there; spaces in your data, you're often there; command substitutions, etc etc.

Comment: For an example of something that `declare -p` will safely escape but `envsubst` can't, consider `myVar=$'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\''`; sure, that example is deliberately malicious, but the worst data loss event I've been personally present for was caused by a filename (that was created by an accident of what was in a memory region that was overwritten due to a bad pointer) being unsafely handled.

Comment: @ Charles Duffy Using -p is a good idea. If you want, go ahead and post a full answer. If it works, I'll mark it as correct.